# how to make click listener for images in horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android

I m making an horizontal Scroll View to display images in Android app.But i dont know how to make click listener for each individual images.My code is

```
    private Integer images[] = {R.drawable.mba, R.drawable.lifestylemin, 
R.drawable.jee,R.drawable.comic,R.drawable.defence};
// private ReaderView mReader;
// ImageView imageGallery;
LinearLayout im1;
LinearLayout imageGallery;
LinearLayout imageGallery2;
ImageView imageView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    // init PlugPDF
    LinearLayout adcat=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.adcat);
    adcat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ebookSelection.class));
        }
    });

     imageGallery = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
    imageGallery2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGallery2);
    addImagesToThegallery();

 //edit code
    for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getImageView(images[i]);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),book.class);
        int id=imageView.getId();
        i.putExtra("id",id);
        startActivity(i);
    }
   });
   }
 ////
    return view;
}
private void addImagesToThegallery() {

    for (Integer image : images) {
        imageGallery.addView(getImageView(image));
        imageGallery2.addView(getImageView(image));
    }
}


private View getImageView(Integer image) {
    ImageView imageView = new  
  ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(260, 400);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    return imageView;
}
```

I want to make individua click listener for each image so that i can perform different tast from different images.
Thanxx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set the OnClickListener on your getImageView Method

EDIT: add a TAG on your imageView with the ImageResource, then recover the TAG on the image OnClick Method, Like This:

```
private View getImageView(Integer image, Integer index) {
    ImageView imageView = new
            ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(260, 400);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
    //Create a TAG on your Strings Resources
    //"IMAGE_TAG" with any value
    imageView.setTag(R.string.IMAGE_TAG, image);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int image = (int)v.getTag(R.string.IMAGE_TAG);
            switch (image)
            {
                case R.drawable.mba:
                {
                    //action for your image
                } break;
                //and so on..

            }
        }
    });

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Ok.but through this method i can not perform different operation for different images.

Comment: you can use your array and perform different actions depending your image index

Comment: check my updated answer, it should work on your case

Comment: thanxx for reply but this line                                                                         int image = (Integer) v.getTag("IMAGE_TAG"); giving me error that View cannot apply to java.lang.String

Comment: My bad!, see updated answer, edited the setTag and getTag lines

Comment: srry for late rply. But ur sol works perfectly as i wanted and thanx for giving ur time to solve this problem.can u help me in this problem url is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115893/how-to-switch-tab-on-click

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to call setOnClickListener on the ImageView for each image.

You could do this in your getImageView method and have different behaviour depending on which image index you've passed to the method, or you could call the following from your for loop.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getImageView(i); 
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Perform action on click
     }
 });
```

Comment: ImageView imageView = getImageView(i); giving error that it require image.widget.ImageView and found image.vie.View.What should i do now?

Comment: Either change the getImageView return type to ImageView instead of View, or cast it as shown in my edited answer

Comment: error gone but it doesn't work like i wanted it. Plz check what i have done wrong in my edit code

Comment: Test are you actually getting to the onClick by putting  a toast or log in the onClick method. If it's getting there but not launching your activity,  you'll need to debug that. That's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the onClick listener for each view inside the for loop or simply use the view.getId method inside the listener you already created and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this inner class inside your Activity/Fragment

```
class ImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case images[0]:
            // handle click for first image
        break;
            //And so on and so forth
    }


}
```

Then simply set the click listener inside the loop for each ImageView

```
for (Integer image : images) {
    ImageView image1 = getImageView(image);
    ImageView image2 = getImageView(image);
    image1.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener());
    image2.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener());
    imageGallery.addView(image1);
    imageGallery2.addView(image2);
}
```