# how to switch tab on click

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three tab and on home tab I have navigation drawer,on which on clicking on a particular item i want to go to tab3 using intent but it doesn't work.
My code is :

```
//Initializing the tablayout
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Read"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Me"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  //  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    //Creating our pager adapter
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(tabLayout.this);


    //// drawable navbar


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // 
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // 
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // 

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(tabLayout.this, new 
   RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    switch(position){
                        case 1:
                            Intent go=new Intent(tabLayout.this,Tab1.class);
                             startActivity(go);
                            break;`
```

Comment: Tabs i.e. Home, Read, Me are activities or fragments?

Comment: these are fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to different items in your ViewPager via:

```
viewpager.setcurrentitem(position,boolean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are switching between fragments not activities. 
In your onclick call the following method

```
public void switchfragment() {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new Tab1());
    ft.commit();
}
```